# Permission denied in DoVoid method of paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I am making a `NVP` api call to `Void` a paypal transaction but I get the following error message

```
DoVoid failed:

Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 20110329 05 42 06
    [CORRELATIONID] => 999a45387463f
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 51.0
    [BUILD] => 1799695
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10007
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Permission denied
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permissions to make this API call
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

I have provided the correct API credentials but don't know why i am getting this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mistake:** I was using the api credentials of different account to void transaction of different account.

**Another Option:** You can grant api permission from one account to another account (but still not working in my case). Have more info [here](https://www.x.com/message/191296;jsessionid=B8AEE49EE2CFF26160BC751919FC5E61.node0?tstart=-19)

**Solution for 2nd Option:** The solution for second option is you will have to pass the paypal email of receiver (of whose the transaction is being going to void ) in the &SUBJECT parameter with paypal transaction id. more info [here](https://www.x.com/message/155763)